How to change macOS terminal background color from command line?
I am trying to programmatically change the background color of my mac terminal following this question, and the accepted answer points to this CSV for a list of colors, to be used with the following osascript:
tell application "Terminal"
   set background color of window 1 to {65535, 33667, 49601}
end tell

I can't seem to find the RGB (?) color for this grayscale slider.

If I change to RGB, I see this:

But when I run the script above with the numbers 25 25 25, I don't see this color — I see complete black.
How do I get this color?

Those sliders are based on 8 bits per color (values 0-255), but the AppleScript command seems to expect 16 bits per color (values 0-65535).
If you want 10% brightness dark grey, set all three colors to 10% of 65535, so {6554, 6554, 6554}.
